# How to insert variable to MySQL table using python

Tags: python, mysql

I have looked all over stack overflow and none of the answers works. This is the code below:

```
var = ""


sql = "INSERT INTO yyc_central (NO) VALUES %s"

mycursor.execute(sql, var)
```

I am using mysql.connector to connect to my database.  I am also getting an error that says:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

Don't mind "line 1" I really need help please and thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `VALUES (%s)`? Also normally you pass a list or tuple as the arguments, e.g. `[var]`

Comment: i tried that but i gave me this error:

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python is somewhat peculiar with only 1 parameter, so

```
var = ""


sql = "INSERT INTO yyc_central (NO) VALUES (%s)"

mycursor.execute(sql, (var,))
```

Comment: Thanks for this awnser